# Libgdx Click for x, y coordinates

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I got a moving square wich moves around in my window and this works fine. But when I try to use public void clicked from libgdx I can't get it to work. This is how my void looks like:

```
public void clicked(InputEvent event,float x,float y){
    rect.y = y;
    rect.x = x;
}
```

Above this im also adding the movement from the box and this works fine so its not rect.y and rect.x. Why aren't rect.y and rect.x changing to the float x and float y from my void when Clicked?

Libgdx Void:

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/utils/ClickListener.html#clicked-com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent-float-float-

Why isn't this working?

Thanks for reading/helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your game's `render` method:

```
if(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Buttons.LEFT)) {
    rect.x = Gdx.input.getX();
    rect.y = Gdx.input.getY();
}
```

`rect` must be defined within your game's class.

Comment: Can you explain this solution a bit more? If i put this code in my gamerederer class it ends up with an error cause rect is private.

Comment: The current mouse location is consistently stored in `Gdx.input`.

Comment: Allright when i try this the square ends up dissapearing from the screen?         if(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Buttons.LEFT)) {
            myWorld.getRect().x = Gdx.input.getX();
            myWorld.getRect().y = Gdx.input.getY();
        }

Comment: As for the placement of this condition, it should always be called in the render loop for continuous testing. If you have a `render` method defined in your `GameRenderer` class and a `rect` object there, you can define a new `GameRenderer` in you game's class and draw indirectly from this object.

Comment: `x` and `y` are the lower left coordinates, you know that right?

Comment: Let me ask a silly question - is your clicked method called at all? Try printing out something to the console and check do you get that output when you click.
Also you did implement needed class and registered your object well, right (sorry for asking this, but let's be sure :) )?